# How can I insert text and variables into a text box in Python tkinter without elements being contained by {}

Tags: python, tkinter, printing, insert, text-widget

I am trying to use a text widget in tkinter to display the output of my code.

```
sequence = ("This peptide contains ", len(Peptide), "total residues", "\n")
text.insert("current", sequence)
```

this seems to work, except for that when it is printed, the
[elements are separated by {}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8wmH.png).

I would prefer for the output to not have these parenthesis, and read like: "This peptide contains 17 total residues". Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: The `insert` method expects a string, not a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `sequence` is a `tuple`.  Try changing it to

```
sequence = "This peptide contains {} total residues\n".format(len(Peptide))
```